# Windows.open automatically adds 'Index' to the url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a button which opens a new pop up window.

HTML Code :

```
  <input type="button" 
         id="TestRegex" 
         name="TestRegex" 
         value="Test Regex"
         class="btn btn-default" />
```

Jquery code:

```
   $("#TestRegex").click(function () {
            window.open("RegularExpressionTest",
                        '',
                        'height=500,
                        width=600,
                        left=-150,
                        top=10,
                        status=no,
                        toolbar=no,
                        resizable=yes,
                        scrollbars=yes');
        });
```

The problem is, when I click the link, it opens a new window however the link of the URL is `http://localhost:00000/FileTypeDetails/Index/RegularExpressionTest.cshtml` however, I wanted it to be `http://localhost:00000/FileTypeDetails/RegularExpressionTest.cshtml`. Index.cshtml is the page which has the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL of the current page is `http://localhost:00000/FileTypeDetails/Index`, so the browser thinks that the `Index` part is a folder. When you open `RegularExpressionTest` the browser thinks that it is a file or folder inside the `Index` folder.

You can use `..` to get out of the "folder" `Index`:

```
window.open("../RegularExpressionTest", '', 'height=500,width=600,left=-150,top=10,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
```

Comment: @YagneshCangi: You can add it to the URL. Example: `window.open("../RegularExpressionTest?id=" + id, ...`.

Comment: I've tried that however, my controller is getting a null value after clinking that button... I've checked the the parameter i'm passing back and its not null

Answer (score 1):

For above problem you have to use "URL.Action" for manipulation of URL
Try following script :

```js
window.open('@Url.Action("RegularExpressionTest", "FileTypeDetails")', '', 'height=500,width=600,left=-150,top=10,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
```

Comment: you can pass parameters through "Url.Action"